# How to get the value of Mean squared error in a linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, error

For a linear regression model obtained by the R function `lm`, I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the Mean Squared Error by a command.

I had the following output of an example:

```
> lm <- lm(MuscleMAss~Age,data)
> sm<-summary(lm)
> sm

Call:
lm(formula = MuscleMAss ~ Age, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.1368  -6.1968  -0.5969   6.7607  23.4731 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 156.3466     5.5123   28.36   <2e-16 ***
Age          -1.1900     0.0902  -13.19   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.173 on 58 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7501,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7458 
F-statistic: 174.1 on 1 and 58 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Is Multiple R-squared the same as sum of square error? If the answer is no, could someone explain the meaning of Multiple R-squared?

Comment: `summary(lm)$sigma2`

Comment: I do not think there is an attribute named `sigma2`. I think the correct way to get the value is `summary(lm)$sigma`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The multiple R-squared that R reports is the [coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), which is given by the formula

$$ R^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_{\text{res}}}{SS_{\text{tot}}}.$$

The sum of squared errors is given (thanks to a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254543/extracting-residual-sum-of-squres-from-mlm-object-in-r)) by `sum(sm$residuals^2)`.

The mean squared error is given by `mean(sm$residuals^2)`. You could write a function to calculate this, e.g.:

```
mse <- function(sm) 
    mean(sm$residuals^2)
```

Comment: +1. Another solution, *based only on what is visible in the output*, is `sm$sigma^2 * sm$fstatistic[3]/(1+sum(sm$fstatistic[2:3]))`. That is, from the antepenultimate row you read off the $8.173$ and $58$ df and in the final row count the number of parameters ($1+1$), giving $8.173^2\times 58/(1+1+58) = 64.57$.

Comment: Antepenultimate is a great word.

Comment: As usual, a much neater way is to write `mse <- function(sm) mean(sm$residuals^2)`

Comment: Thanks- I didn't know that syntax was equivalent. I'll update my answer.

Comment: >Isn't it that mean squared error is given by residuals^2 / error df from the ANOVA table instead of mean(residuals^2). The latter is mean prediction error square. Not sure if I'm missing some understanding. Sorry, I dont have enough reputation points to post a comment.

Comment: But I agree what user45409 said. According to what I learned, MSE = residuals^2 / error df.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had a higher reputation to post an answer here, but the correct answer (which includes degrees of freedom) is `sum(sm $residuals^2)/df.residual(sm)`. Similar to simply taking the mean, but we can think of this as a weighted mean against the number of parameters in our regression model.

Comment: If you can show me a source, I'll update my answer. Other languages use the sum of squared residuals divided by the number of samples, e.g. Python, in [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b7e3702/sklearn/metrics/regression.py#L176). [ESL](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) also defines MSE as $E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2]$. `sum(sm$residuals^2)/df.resdual(sm)` is, I believe (but could be wrong), a consistent, unbiased estimator for the variance, which is different than MSE.

Comment: The `mean(sm$residuals^2)` doesn't give the accurate MSE of the model. It should be `sum(sm$residuals^2)/df.resdual(sm)`.

Comment: Regarding the SSE, doesn't `deviance(sm)` remove the need for an SSE function?

Answer (score 3):

Another simple method is to use the `anova` function.

You can get the MSE with `anova(model)['Residuals', 'Mean Sq']`

```
> print(sprintf("MSE=%0.2f", sum(lmfit$residuals^2)/lmfit$df.residual))
[1] "MSE=0.27"
> print(sprintf("MSE=%0.2f", anova(lmfit)['Residuals', 'Mean Sq']))
[1] "MSE=0.27"
```